# Give thread delay inside timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, delay

I want to make thread have delay 3 sec / repeat function thread every 3 sec inside a timer function.

What should I do?

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Task taskA = new Task(() => Function1()); // This is thread what I meant
  taskA.Start();
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Why not just have your timer tick every three seconds? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Are you aware that the `System.Timers.Timer` class will raise its `Elapsed` event on a thread pool thread by default? Maybe just use one of those instead of a WinForms `Timer`. Just set the `Interval` to 3000 and you now have some code being executed on a secondary thread every 3 seconds. Don't complicate that which doesn't need to be.

Comment: i have 2 function in 1 timer  example taskA and taskB how make function running different times?

Comment: What do you mean "running at different times". You really need to describe your actual goal.

Comment: i meant i have taskA runing every 1 sec and i have taskB running every 3 sec

how to give delay for taskA.Start();

Comment: Is there any relation between taskA and taskB? If so, why not run them on the same timer tick? If not, why do you care about the delay?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Windows Forms timer then this would do it:

```
var timerA = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timerA.Tick += (s, e) => Task.Run(() => Function1());
timerA.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0).TotalMilliseconds;
timerA.Enabled = true;

var timerB = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timerB.Tick += (s, e) => Task.Run(() => Function2());
timerB.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0).TotalMilliseconds;
timerB.Enabled = true;
```